# Password managers for iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, security, password

With the whole Heartbleed mess, I figured it was about time to start using a password manager. After doing some research, here is the list of things that I want and don't want in this kind of software:

I want:

- Open source, or at least with source code available, so that people can check for themselves for security holes (though Heartbleed
  happened in another piece of open source code, so who knows now...).
- Iphone support. My phone is the one thing I always carry with me, no matter what desktop computer I'm using.

What I DON'T need:

- Dropbox syncing. I don't want my passwords to be on any cloud, thanks.
- Form autocomplete. I can type my own passwords, thanks.

After searching for a bit, it looks like miniKeePass is the software that fits my needs best. Can anyone comment on its security track record, or suggest alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: re autocomplete - typing 30 characters including several shifts is tricky on an iPhone - having autocomplete does help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used both [KeePass](http://keepass.info) and [MiniKeePass](http://minikeepass.github.io) in the past and can confirm that they are great and work perfectly — they work very simply but excel at what they do: simple password management. They seem great for your needs.

Answer (score 5):

I personally love [1Password](https://1password.com), it is a great solution for iOS and Mac, they have an really good and fast syncing option (you can choose if you want to use iCloud, Dropbox or you can sync with the Mac app via wifi), the Developer just updated the app for iOS 7.

The only disadvantage per your requirements is that it is not open-source.

Comment: I'm using 1Password for years, and couldn't live w/o it, here my review : http://geer.fr/struggling-to-remember-all-your-passwords/

Answer (score 1):

### [pwSafe](http://app77.com/pwSafe/)

Some features worth noting (taken from the site):

- **Open Source**
- Unlimited safes, passwords and groups
- Universal app - iPad and iPhone/iPod Touch with a single app
- Search in all fields (title, username, password, URL, email and notes)

It has Dropbox sync (as an optional in-app purchase) and iCloud sync - which you can always turn off iCloud syncing for the app in Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data > pwSafe.

Answer (score -2):

I am using an app call "one key" and it was excellent. It not only store your password, it can store others things that need security. It provide 128-bit encryption which is really high security for iOS device.

Please note normal iOS apps are not open source which is to prevent people discover bugs and security holes.

Comment: "128-bit encryption" says NOTHING about security. Also, your last point isn't true, as security by obscurity never worked.

Comment: "128 bit encryption" is use by US government(128 bit encryption =AES) it is a method to encrypt data!! It will take years for a supercomputer to solve the encrypted data.

Comment: Again. 128 bit does not say anything about the algorithm used.

Comment: re Open source - the HartBleed and Apple ssh bugs were both in Open Source code thus in itself Open Source is not a guide to security